# Open set in subspace not open in the entire space example

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am stuck with the following problem: X is a metric space. Suppose that Y is a subspace of X. Give an example that an open set in Y is not open in X.

My own approach was this: Suppose U is a subset of the rational numbers in the open set Y = (0,1). All elements in (0,1) is contained in real numbers. U is an open subspace of (0,1), but not in X.

Is my reasoning true? If not, could you please give me a clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your approach is doomed if $Y$ is open in $X$. Since the open sets of subspace $Y$ are intersections of open sets in $X$ with $Y$, and if $Y$ is open, these interesections of two open sets in $X$ will be open in $X$.

Comment: If I understand your example correctly, it does not work. It seems that you're taking $Y=(0,1)$ and $U=\Bbb Q\cap(0,1).$ This fails to be open in the real interval $Y,$ under the usual metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=[0,1]$ and $X$ be the real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

What space are you using for $X$? I think this is an easier example:

Let $X = \Bbb{R}$ with the standard topology. Let $Y = (0,1]$. We know $\left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2} \right)$ is an open subset of $X$, so $Y \cap \left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2} \right) = \left( \frac{1}{2},1 \right]$ is open in $Y$. However, it is clear that $\left( \frac{1}{2},1 \right]$ is not open in $X$.

Comment: X is a metric space

Comment: You should state that in your problem description above then. Your tag simply states "general-topology". My example still works, because the Euclidean Distance metric is equivalent to the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: is my example true?

Comment: I don't think so. You need to provide a counterexample, which means you need to explicitly define your metric space. As stated above, it is not clear weather or not $Y$ is open in $X$. For the counterexample to work, you need to start with a subspace that is NOT open in $X$. If that is true of what you have said above, then you are fine.